# material 11 - unable to right justify 2 out of 5 columns mat-header-cell when mat-sort-header is applied

Tags: css, angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9HIn.png)I'm using Angular material 11.  When defining each column header using *matHeaderCellDef with mat-header-cell and when mat-sort-header applied, I am in a situation where I am unable to apply the desired style.   I'm able to right justify the content of cells underneath the headers by applying align="right".   However, not only is that not allowed for the header, but it seems that adding css class to provide any adjustments is not performing adequately when mat-sort-header is applied.   It seems that mat-sort-header ends up constructing a child element with inline styling that overrides any css class applying above.

I've tried many things, including other posts that inspired ideas.  However, haven't seen this exact issue anywhere.

I have 2 columns:  "weight" and "values" which I'm trying to right justify the column titles.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6zim4q?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-filtering-example%2Ftable-filtering-example.component.css)

I appreciate any help with this.   Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your header right using the below style

```
:host ::ng-deep .headerRight .mat-sort-header-content {
  justify-content: flex-end !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

[image: This is how it looks like]

Comment: thank you for the tip.   I just tried updating the stackblitz using that same style, however it did not make a change.

Comment: I can see it right aligned here. I just removed the commented out code. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xcrmhj?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-filtering-example%2Ftable-filtering-example.component.css

Comment: Hmm.  I checked firefox, chrome, safari, edge... the only part that is right justified are the cells.   The column header titles are still left-justified. What browser are you using ?     (I added an image at the top of what I'm seeing)

Comment: I am using Chrome and try to see this output in fullscreen. The space remaining at the end is for sort icon. Check the stackblitz which I have shared above

Comment: thank you for that.  I tried even your stackblitz (in full screen) and in all browsers the titles "Weight" and "Values" are still not right justified.   They don't line up with the content in the columns below those titles.  The content in the columns are right justified.

Comment: I am now seeing the image you posted above.   It demonstrates that the title is not right justified.  In other words, I still see the issue even in the screenshot you provided. I appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Please note sort icon is also there which is visible on hover.

Comment: I now see your point.  I apologize as the width looked much wider than that of the sort icon.  Anyone reading this can apply arrowPosition="before" to have the sort icon appear on the left.    Thank you for your help.